# libgdx does not recognize Facebook Android SDK

Tags: gradle, libgdx, facebook-android-sdk

I added Facebook's Android SDK to my `libgdx` project, in the Android-specific sub project, by following the [official tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#androidstudio). I did this by adding Facebook SDK as a dependency in my `build.gradle` like this:

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        ...
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    }
}
```

This succeeded apparently since the Facebook SDK was downloaded and put into the Android project:

[image]

However, in the `AndroidLauncher` class, when I try to `import` Facebook SDK related classes (step 6 in the above tutorial):

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
```

I get a compilation error:

> The import com.facebook cannot be resolved

What I tried so far:

- Refreshing Gradle dependencies
- Performing a Build Clean
- Restarting Eclipse

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that [Eclipse cannot use aar files](http://www.iphonedroid.com/blog/en/utilizar-ficheros-aar-en-eclipse/#.Vf1Au52qqko). To fix this, I followed the required steps to fix that, as described in the above link.

**Update**

After fixing this issue, my app was crashing due to a "class not found" error. So eventually I gave up on eclipse, and moved to android-studio. No errors now!